# Need help identifying SMD DFN-6 component. Top marking 26T6 TIW 957M

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, oscillator, reverse-engineering

I've been trying to reverse-engineer this circuit but I'm an ME, so my knowledge of electronics is limited to pretty much Arduinos.

I have a simple circuit and I'm trying to identify one of the components.

The component is a small IC, DFN-6 (3x3) package size, and is wired as shown in the drawn schematic. The part number that I can make out I think is 26T6 TIW 957M.

The circuit is on a lithium BMS board and is used for the initial handshake when connecting a tool to the battery.

The circuit is separate from the rest of the BMS as I've isolated the components.

With the circuit isolated, applying a 1 kHz positive square wave produces the signal shown in the below oscilloscope screen capture.

What I've concluded is that it's some sort of fixed/pre-programmed oscillator, but the input is the same as the output...?

(Click on an image for a larger version)

[image: Traced schematic]

*Figure 1: Traced schematic*

[image: Oscilloscope capture]

*Figure 2: Oscilloscope capture*

[image: Top marking on unknown device]

*Figure 3: Top marking on unknown device*

[image: PCB showing unknown device]

*Figure 4: PCB showing unknown device*

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a 1-wire temperature sensor and unique ID something like this although the package is different:

[1-Wire® Temperature Sensor](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/sensors/MAX31820.html/product-details/tabs-2?intcid=para):

Battery charging is critically dependent on measuring the battery temperature
[image]

Comment: There's a separate circuit and pin for an NTC thermistor that's embedded directly against the lithium cells. This chip is placed far any current path or other components that I think would need temp monitoring.

Comment: @ericthepoolboy It's definitely a 1-wire something. Maybe some kind of ID chip, to say that it's a genuine battery pack for whatever tool it's used with--unfortunately a fairly common practice.